# Docker tomcat not finding application logs

Tags: java, docker, debugging, tomcat, logging

I'm planning to deploy my web application in tomcat docker. 
user 
tomcat9 
OpenJDK-11

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:jdk11-corretto
WORKDIR /
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/tomcat/
ADD target/mvn-webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

My application is running. But i'm not seeing the application logs file. 
i.e

```
mvn-webapp.log
```

in /usr/local/tomcat/log folder

Can someone help me to enable app log files in the docker?

```
sh-4.2# ls -o
total 12
-rw-r----- 1 root 5159 Jun  6 16:18 catalina.2020-06-06.log
-rw-r----- 1 root    0 Jun  6 16:18 host-manager.2020-06-06.log
-rw-r----- 1 root    0 Jun  6 16:18 localhost.2020-06-06.log
-rw-r----- 1 root   78 Jun  6 16:19 localhost_access_log.2020-06-06.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root    0 Jun  6 16:18 manager.2020-06-06.log
```

i am seeing the other logs not my applogs

Answer (score 1):

In Docker usually the logs are not saved in a file inside the container, but instead can be accessed using `docker logs` command.

The reason for that is the container can be restarted/removed, and then all your logs will be lost.
The common practice is to store the logs externally (using Kibana or equilvalent), that way you will still have your logs if your container is removed and rebuilt